# Sidebar в woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно добавить сайдбар в магазин woocommerce и в его внутренние страницы ? Не могу найти ни как, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться стандартными средствами регистрации и вывода сайдбара в WordPress.

В файле функций зарегистрируйте сайдбар:

```
function castom_register_wp_sidebars() {

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id' => 'castom_side', // уникальный id
            'name' => 'Боковая колонка', // название сайдбара
            'description' => 'Перетащите сюда виджеты, чтобы добавить их в сайдбар.', // описание
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="side widget %2$s">', // по умолчанию виджеты выводятся <li>-списком
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">', // по умолчанию заголовки виджетов в <h2>
            'after_title' => '</h3>'
        )
    );

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'castom_register_wp_sidebars' );
```

В корне вашей темы создайте файл "sidebar.php", а внутри:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'castom_side' ) ) : ?>

    <div id="true-side" class="sidebar">

        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'castom_side' ); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Дальше в зависимости от того как вы работаете с шаблонами WooCommerce( в файле "woocommerce.php", или "ваша_тема/woocommerce/archive-product.php" ) в нужном месте добавьте:

```
<?php get_sidebar() ?>
```

Функция `get_sidebar()` выведет всё что внутри файла "sidebar.php" который в корне темы. Если его нет, то подключает "wp-includes/theme-compat/sidebar.php".

Comment: Видимо я что то делаю совсем не так, не получилось к сожалению ( Пошел разбирать шаблон . Спасибо

Comment: @Cowboy На каком этапе не работает? После регистрации через `add_action( 'widgets_init', 'castom_register_wp_sidebars' );`. По пути  "Внешний вид > Виджеты" в админке появляется ли поле для виджетов "Боковая колонка"?

Comment: @Cowboy Если появится, перетащите туда например виджет "HTML-код" и напишите что то. Дальше впишите куда либо в вашей теме строку `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'castom_side' ); ?>` чтобы проверить что виджеты в сайдбаре выводит

Comment: Все, спасибо огромное ! Нашел файл где указано родное имя сайдбара основной темы и вписал его в <?php get_sidebar() ?> . Столько времени на такой тривиальный вопрос ) Спасибо за вектор, так бы долго еще сидел